# IFormfile in a view model is not binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using a viewmodel in .net standard project in my asp.net 4.72 framework mvc application and I have a file upload functionality in the app. IFormfile is always null in the controller method. Below are my model, view and controller method.

Model in .Net core

```
 public class CustomerImportForm
    {
        public CustomerImportForm();

        [Required]
        public int CohortId { get; set; }
        public ImporterType ImporterType { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public IFormFile ImportFile { get; set; }
    }
```

View in Asp.net 4.7

```
@model CustomerImportForm
<div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ImportFile)

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="custom-file">

                                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input"
                                       id="@Html.IdFor(m => m.ImportFile)"
                                       name="@Html.NameFor(m => m.ImportFile)"
                                       accept=".xlsx,.csv"
                                       required/>

                                <label class="custom-file-label" for="@Html.IdFor(m => m.ImportFile)">Choose file</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ImportFile, null, new {@class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
```

Controller Method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ProcessUploadAndCreateCohorts(CustomerImportForm form)
        {

            Log.Info("Uploading import '{0}'", form.ImportFile.FileName);
            return RedirectToAction("View", new { id = importId });
        }
```

The form.ImportFile is always null.

Comment: check the enctype attribute of the form. Is it set to `multipart/form-data`. However the most confusing part about the question is that you are using IFormFile interaface in .NetFramework. It is only applicable in Asp.Net Core [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile?view=aspnetcore-2.2#applies-to), as it comes from the the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http namespace which is available in the Microsoft.AspNetCore metapackage so it technically cannot be used inside a .net standard class. Hope this clears things for you.

Comment: I did not have it in the above code but the form is set to `multipart/form-data`, but still the IFormFile is null. I have my view model in a .Net Standard standard project but the web app is in .Net framewrok. We recently did a migration from framework to core, but left the web apps in the framework platform itself. hence I could only use IFormFile instead of httppostedfilebase in my view model.

Comment: Solved the issue by moving the view model to the framework solution and using httppostedfilebase instead of IFormfile

Comment: framework solution? Is it .Net framework you're talking about?

Comment: can you write the solution as answer please @anusha-karaska